# Manifest merger failed in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

While running react-native run-android I am getting below exception. I have tried some changes what I found on google, but not working. below are my exception and gradle file. Is there any update from Google side?
How can I fix this? I am facing this problem since yesterday.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91

**build .gradle,..\app**

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_netinfo')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  }

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
```

Please suggest ..
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this using

```
npm uninstall react-native-device-info
```

and then

```
npm install --save react-native-device-info
```

latest version should be  2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

If your not using react-native-device-info

then worth looking at:
[React-native manifest merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732908/react-native-manifest-merger-failed)